# Automated way to code for uploading file in ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, file-upload

I am fairly new to this topic. I can somehow make the code work to upload a file like picture by coding everything from scratch but with ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework being so automated these days through scaffolding, I assume there must be a very straightforward way to add file upload to a scaffolded Entity Framework solution.

Does anyone know about such a way?

Comment: Well, while scaffolding in ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework Core does not automatically generate file upload functionality, you have to mannually add it to your scaffolded solution.

Comment: To upload a file, you should follow these steps: 1. Include some HTML lines (input type="file"...) in your view to choose the local file to upload; 2. If you want, write few lines of javascript to upload the file (with a progress bar also...); 3. Use an action of type [HttpPost] to handle the uploaded file saving it into a server folder; 4. Insert the file (or its url only) in your database with Entity Framework.

Comment: @FabioCaruso awesome ! That is what I am looking for , the very basic way to use EF  Don’t you mind to share the codes for those steps if you have something handy ? This would be actually the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a file in your ASP.NET Core project, you should first insert some lines in your View .cshtml file, like these (I prefer to use javascript code to upload and POST the file, so I can put a progress bar also):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function uploadFile(currentForm) {

    let File1 = currentForm.querySelector("#File1").files[0];

    let fileName = currentForm.querySelector("#File1").value;
    fileName = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")).substr(1);
    currentForm.querySelector("#fileName").innerHTML = fileName;

    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", File1);

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "/Home/UploadFile";
    let filePath = "";
    currentForm.querySelector("#progressBar").hidden = false;

    request.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        filePath = request.responseText;            
        currentForm.querySelector("#fileLoaded").innerHTML = filePath;
    });

    request.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
        let percentual = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        currentForm.querySelector("#progressBar").value = percentual;
    });

    request.open("POST", url);
    request.send(data);
}

</script>

<form id="Form1" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">    
    <!-- with this enctype the file will not be submitted with the form -->

    <input type="file" id="File1" name="File1" onchange="uploadFile(this.form)" style="display:none">
    <input type="button" value="Choose..." onclick="this.form.querySelector('#File1').click()">
    <span id="fileName"></span>                
    <progress hidden id="progressBar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
    <br />
    <label id="fileLoaded"> Uploaded file path: None </label>
    
</form>
```

After that, you need an action (here is in your HomeController) which receives the file posted from the web with javascript, saving it in a server folder, and putting its URL in a property of your Entity Framework database context model (ie. FileRow containing UploadedFileURL):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ContentResult UploadFile()
    {

        string filePath = "";
        string fileName = "";

        if (Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];

            if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
            {
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                filePath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath + @"/Uploads/" + fileName;
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);                        
                }
                
                FileRow fileRow = new FileRow()
                {
                    UploadedFileURL = filePath
                };                                    
                _dbContext.Add(fileRow);
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }                                    
        return Content(filePath);
    }
}
```

The file will be saved in **wwwroot/Uploads** folder.

Comment: `filePath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath + @"/Uploads/" + fileName;` <-- It's very inadvisble to save user-uploaded files to a publicly accessible location.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but if the uploaded file is an image that is to be displayed, I believe the choice is obligatory, and keep in mind however that, usually, a user who can make an upload must be at least authenticated. Otherwise **ContentRootPath** could be used.